# What are the correct uses of @NonNull and @Nullable?

Tags: java, android, annotations

I am confused about the correct use of these annotations.

```
android.support.annotation.NonNull;
android.support.annotation.Nullable;
```

The information in the documentation for `@NonNull` says:

> Denotes that a parameter, field or method return value can never be null.

What does this mean in the case of parameters, when there's nothing to stop you passing `null`?

For example, suppose I have a class `MyObject` and that an instance may or may not have a title.

```
public final class MyObject {

    private String title = null;

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        if (title == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void clearTitle() {
        title = null;
    }
}
```

Here I am using `null` to represent the absence of a title, but this is an implementation detail, so I wouldn't want a single method for setting and clearing the title.

If I mark the field `title` as `@Nullable`, android studio tells me that the parameter to `setTitle` should probably be marked `@Nullable` too (but this is the opposite of what I want).

If I mark the parameter to the `setTitle` method as `@NonNull` I get a warning that the condition `title == null` is always `false`.

What is the correct use of these annotations in a case like this? If `@NonNull` means that a parameter *can* never be `null` is it wrong to use it to mean *should* not be `null`? If yes, is there a correct way to indicate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that this annotation is some kind of contract, so you don't need to make checks if you annoate your methods correctly. Android Studio will check that you don't mess with it. You can still ignore it, but this will result  compiler warnings.

If you omit that useless (by contract) security checks it will properly throw nullpointerexceptions. But the developer was warned with your annotation.

Comment: In general, the checks are still required.  The annotations assist the IDE in understanding the contract.  Some IDEs go further and generate runtime errors, though such runtime checking by the IDE is a courtesy, not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

`@Nonnull` and `@Nullable` are declarative. This is a hint to fellow software developers. You tell them, that a parameter can be a null value, or that it must not.

If you mark a parameter with the `@Nonnull` annotation, you tell every person using your API that they should not pass a null value here, otherwise they have to deal with the consequences (e.g. `NullPointerException`).

You can use it to declare, the parameter SHOULD not be null, this is a valid use case, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you mark the argument @NonNull then the user of your method is required to do the null check, since @NonNull will not catch NPEs at runtime. So for instance, if you had a utility class with helper methods that check for null before executing, then you would mark those arguments as @Nullable since you technically can pass a null value, but are safely checking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and mark the parameter to the `setTitle` method as `@NonNull`.

This will ensure the compiler issues an error when some code calls `setTitle` with a value that *may be null*. So the compiler ensures `setTitle` is *never* called with a `null`. Therefore your can remove the `null` check in your method, making the 'title == null is always false' warning go away.

I.e. your code will look like this:

```
public final class MyObject {

    private String title = null;

    public void setTitle(@NonNull String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void clearTitle() {
        title = null;
    }
}
```

(Note: I am not using Android Studio but I guess it behaves similar to Eclipse. In Eclipse I get an error `Null type mismatch: required '@NonNull String' but the provided value is null(/inferred as @Nullable)` when trying to pass null or expressions that may be null to setTitle.)

BTW: also annotating the definition of field `title` with `@Nullable` will make it more explicit `title` may also contain `null` values.